# JS: why does this return true?

Tags: javascript

```
0 + 1 === 1 || 1 + 1 === 2 || 2 + 1 === 10
```

Can someone please explain why this statement returns **true**?

Individually, the first two are true and the last one is false. However **OVERALL**, the statement  returns true.  It seems that you just need one true statement among a longer list of statements to make the OVERALL statement return true.   Is that correct?

Just trying to cement my understanding of Booleans. Cheers.

Comment: I dont get it, you first ask why it returns true, then you say it returns false. which is it?

Comment: @user3716264: I believe he believes it should be false, but somehow isn't.

Comment: Pretty straightforward... as everyone is mentioning your statement contains logical OR operators (||), and you're expecting logical ANDs (&&). For what it's worth, the second and third portions of your statement will never even get evaluated to determine whether they are true or false in this case. Once the first segment evaluated true, JavaScript moved on.

Comment: Update: sorry, in the second sentence I had said 'False' when I meant 'True'  - fixed now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, `||` returns the first truthy value if there is one so:

```
1 || ANYTHING_IN_THE_WORLD ; // returns 1
```

So all you really have there is

```
0 + 1 === 1
```

Which is true. So yes, your understanding is correct.

---

Expanding on execution order:

[Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) is in play here:

```
0 + 1 === 1 || 1 + 1 === 2 || 2 + 1 === 10
```

First we have addition:

```
1 === 1 || 2 === 2 || 3 === 10
```

Then we have equality checks:

```
true || true || false;
```

Which as explained above `true || ANYTHING_AT_ALL` is true, so the final output is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

`||` is an `or` operator.  So if condition one *or* condition two *or* condition 3 is true, the statement is true.

I suggest reading up on JavaScript here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

it returns true because with OR operator (||) first true will return true.

The evaluation will perform :

```
> 1- is (0+1===1)
```

=> true! Then returns true.

This

```
> 0+1===1 || 1+1000===1
```

will return true for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

"some apples are purple OR some apples are green" is true because it is sufficient that some apples are green. `a OR b` will be true when either or both are true. `a AND b` needs both to be true.

Thus, the fact that some of the items in your expression are true makes the whole expression true. It would not be if you replaced `||` with `&&`.

In fact,

> It seems that you just need one true statement among a longer list of statements to make the OVERALL statement return true. Is that correct?

is (almost) exactly correct. The only correction I'd put in is replacing "true" with "truthy", at least in the context of JavaScript. For example, `3 || 5` is not `true`, but `3` - while `3` is not `true`, it *is* truthy.